# Javascript semicolumn cuts message send with UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script

I really can't understand this behavior:

I have a Google Script App which tries to send a message to another server:

```
   var payload =
   {
     'message' : 'test1;test2';

   };


   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
      muteHttpExceptions: true

   };

   try{
     var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("mywebsite", options);
   }
    catch(e){
      Logger.log("Exception in sending data");
      return false;
    }
```

The server, which is running Django with Django-rest-framework, only receives 'test1' ... everything that is after the ; gets cut.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing I got consistent results regardless of using single or double quotes in the payload object which leads me to believe this might be something on the server side that doesn't like the single quotes.

```
function myFunction() {
  var test1 = {"value1" : "something;something"};
  var test2 = {"value2" : 'something;something'};
  var test3 = {"firstvar" : test1,
           "secondvar" : test2};

  Logger.log(test1);
  Logger.log(test2);
  Logger.log(test3);
}
```

Gave me consistent logging results

```
[14-01-25 22:22:00:460 EST] {value1=something;something}
[14-01-25 22:22:00:460 EST] {value2=something;something}
[14-01-25 22:22:00:460 EST] {secondvar={value2=something;something}, firstvar=      {value1=something;something}}
```

So my suggestion is to try this using double quotes, and see if the payload comes through intact:

```
var payload = {"message" : "test1;test2"};
```

When testing this with http://www.posttestserver.com/ UrlFetchApp.fetch() worked with both single and double quotes, again leading me to thinking this is how your server is handling the payload data.